# Rails 3 - How do I join on a table and filter for last X days?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, join, has-many

I have Clients that has_many Transactions.  I want to select all Clients who haven't had any transactions in the last 30 days (Transaction has a transaction_date) and display the client's name and the last transaction date.

How can I do this query in rails?

Answer (score 2):

In your transaction model:

```
scope :trans_order => (:order => "transaction date ASC")
```

In your controller

```
@inactive_clients = 
Client(:include => :transactions).where
("max(transaction_date) < ? AND transaction_date IS NOT NULL", 
Time.now - 30.days)
```

Then in your view:

```
@inactive_clients .each |client|
  = client.name
  = client.transactions.trans_order.last.transaction_date
end
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand... I'm looking for clients who haven't had any transactions in the last 30 days.  Transactions will always have a transaction_date (it cannot be null).

Comment: Will there be a transaction BEFORE the 30 day period that you want to report on? I think the q didn't make that clear.

Comment: Maybe.  If they have never had a transaction, then it is ok to not return.  If their last transaction is 29 days ago, I don't want it returned.  If there last transaction was 31 days ago, I want it in the list.  Basically trying to show a list of clients who have paid before but haven't made any payments in over a month.

Answer (score 1):

```
@client_transactions = Transaction.includes(:client).where('transaction_date < ?', 30.days.ago).group(:client_id)
@client_transactions.each do |client_transaction| 
  puts "client is #{client_transaction.client.name}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a not exists clause like

```
@clients = Client.where("not exists (select 'x' from 
    transactions where transactions.client_id = clients.id 
    and transaction_date > ?)", 
  30.days.ago)
```